# How to link ruby pg to my own libpq.so

Tags: ruby, linker

I have customized my own postgresql client and postgresql client-devel package and I want it to be available to Ruby programmer. So the command to install ruby pg gem is as below:

```
gem install pg  -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/bin/pg_config --with-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/lib"
```

The command works pretty good if there is only my own postgresql installed.

My pg_config output looks good:

```
BINDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/bin 
DOCDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/doc 
HTMLDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/doc 
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/include 
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/include 
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/include/server 
LIBDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/lib 
PKGLIBDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/lib 
LOCALEDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/share/locale 
MANDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/man 
SHAREDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/share 
SYSCONFDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/etc
PGXS = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk 
VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.0.0
```

However, if there are both official and my customized postgresql installed. The installed driver will be linked against official libpq.so instead of my own libpq.so. 
Is there any way to force ruby-pg to be linked against my own libpq.so? Any clue or hint will be appreciated.

If I can't do this in this way, how would I customize the gem to link to my library?

Comment: What is the output from local pg_config when two PostgreSQL versions are installed?

Comment: The local pg_config output is as follows:
`BINDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/bin
DOCDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/doc
HTMLDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/doc
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/include
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/include/server
LIBDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/lib
PKGLIBDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/lib
LOCALEDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/share/locale
MANDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/man
SHAREDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/share
SYSCONFDIR = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/etc`
@greg-dan

Comment: `PGXS = /usr/local/mypostgres-1.0/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.0.0`